# POST with multiple fields having the same name

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to gather some data from an API that requires POST parameters like this

```
POST /v2/address/addr/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.omniwallet.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
addr=test1&addr=test2
```

CURL version

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "addr=test1&addr=test2" "https://api.omniwallet.org/v2/address/addr/"
```

https://api.omniwallet.org/#doc-general-notes

Problem is that as you can see the fields have the same name "addr".

So i tried to put the data in a array called "addr"

```
var options = { 'method' : 'POST' ,'payload' : { addr: [ "test1", "test2"] } };
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.omniwallet.org/v2/address/addr/', options);
```

but it didn't worked, server does not recognizes the form data fields on the list "addr".
Also tried

```
var options = { 'method' : 'POST' ,'payload' : { addr: "test1", addr: "test2" } };
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.omniwallet.org/v2/address/addr/', options);
```

But it also doesn't work cause it will consider only the value of the second "addr" field (obviously).

Are there anyways of executing this POST method in some other way where i can force the "addr=test1&addr=test2" like in the CURL example ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just send the same string as payload

Comment: Maybe try:  `var options={'method' : 'POST' };var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.omniwallet.org/v2/address/addr/?addr=test1&addr=test2', options);`  I think that you can add a search string to the URL even though it's a POST request.

Comment: Sending as a QueryString doesn't work. The response is "{"error":"no address in dictionary"}". Sending the same string as payload as proposed by @TheMaster  solved the problem.

Comment: @Bruno   Great. Consider accepting the solution below, which states the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to convert the curl command to Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct and the server you want to use needs the values as the form data, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your curl command, the values of `addr=test1&addr=test2` is sent as the form of `"addr": ["test1", "test2"]`.

  - At your 1st try, the array of `addr` cannot be parsed.
  - At your 2nd try, only `addr: "test2"` is sent because of the same key is used.

When above points are reflected to the script, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `options` was modified. I think that this is the same result with [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster).

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  payload: 'addr=test1&addr=test2', // Modified
};
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.